# Functional Where-In Clause - Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, associations, where-clause

I've got an association table that groups accounts together.

I'm trying to select a subset of table 'target'

```
p_group_id := 7;

select *
target t
where  t.account_id in get_account_ids(p_group_id);
```

Is it possible to write a function that returns a list of account_ids (as some form of collection) that would facilitate the above code?

I've looked at pipelined functions, however I want to stay away from loops and cursors. Also, custom types / table also get into casting that I'd like to avoid.

For reference, here's some pseudocode for what the function 'get_account_ids' would do, hypothetically:

```
function get_account_ids(p_group_id) 
  insert into v_ret
  select aa.account_id
  from   assoc_account aa
  where  aa.groupid = p_group_id;

return v_ret;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply need:

```
select *
from   target t
where  t.account_id in 
       ( select aa.account_id
         from   assoc_account aa
         where  aa.groupid = 7;
       )
```

The above will work, assuming that `assoc_account.account_id` is never `NULL`.